# Stream api to spilt ArrayList in batches based on conditions

Tags: java, java-8

Given the following example seed:

```
    List<EmailGroupingDataDTO> emailDataToGroup = Arrays.asList(
            buildEmailGroupingDto(1L, "member_number_1", "username_1", "group_code_1"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(2L, "member_number_1", "username_1", "group_code_1"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(3L, "member_number_1", "username_2", "group_code_1"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(4L, "member_number_1", "username_2", "group_code_1"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(5L, "member_number_1", "username_2", "group_code_3"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(6L, "member_number_2", "username_1", "group_code_1"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(7L, "member_number_2", "username_1", "group_code_2"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(8L, "member_number_2", "username_1", "group_code_2"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(9L, "member_number_3", "username_1", "group_code_1"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(10L, "member_number_3", "username_1", "group_code_1"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(11L, "member_number_3", "username_1", "group_code_2"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(12L, "member_number_3", "username_1", "group_code_2"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(13L, "member_number_3", "username_1", "group_code_3"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(14L, "member_number_4", "username_1", "group_code_3"),
            buildEmailGroupingDto(15L, "member_number_4", "username_1", "group_code_3")
    );
```

I want to create a List of Lists (batches) based on whether either one of the following properties changes when iterating through the list:

```
private boolean isEmailDataEqual(EmailGroupingDataDTO currDto, EmailGroupingDataDTO nextDto) {
    return currDto.getMemberNumber().equals(nextDto.getMemberNumber())
        && currDto.getUsername().equals(nextDto.getGroupCode())
        && currDto.getGroupCode().equals(nextDto.getGroupCode());
}
```

Through regular iteration I can manage this myself probably.
However the question I have is whether there is a stream api that can manage this declaratively.

Comment: Did you try Collectors.toMap ??

Comment: @Antoniossss Every property change should trigger the start of a new list iteratively. Ie. it's not regular aggregation.

Comment: Most of this is doable with a set of nested `flatMap`s, but the indexes at the beginning make it much harder without using a library or something.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks for reasonable explanation. I'm just writing an iterator; was hoping for a simple declarative stream api but it's ok. Btw those indexes are just properties. It's nothing but a constructor hidden behind a factory method to skip fields I didn't need for the unit test.

Comment: @html_programmer you can have statefull collector that will do exactly that. It is simple aggregation - its just key that is generated by comparing current and previous elements. I think that in non parallel stream, order is guaranteed, therfore it should work.

Comment: @Antoniossss I've tried a number of aggregations but didn't achieve the desired result. Anyhow it doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: Close the question if it does not matter.

Comment: @Antoniossss `collect()` always respects the stream order if implemented properly.

Comment: How is that? In case of parralel stream for example?

Answer (score 2):

[StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) will do this for you:

```
List<List<EmailGroupingDataDTO>> groups = StreamEx.of(emailDataToGroup)
        .groupRuns(this::isEmailDataEqual)
        .toList();
```

Comment: Upvoted this as it might work. Haven't tried this though as I won't add a full library for this simple thing. Solved this through regular iteration.

Comment: I will review this if it turns out that we need this and other methods in other places in our batch processes which may be worth adding the library.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AtomicInteger & AtomicReference` for the classifier of `Collectors.groupingBy` and build a map (and get the grouped batches using `Map.values`). Integer as group key and reference as a representative element of a group and to enable an easy way of comparison for your attributes.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

....


List<EmailGroupingDataDTO> emailDataToGroup = //your list 

AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();
AtomicReference<EmailGroupingDataDTO> myRef = new AtomicReference<>(emailDataToGroup.get(0));

Collection<List<EmailGroupingDataDTO>> result =  
        emailDataToGroup.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myDto -> {
            boolean equal = isEmailDataEqual(myDto, myRef.get());
            if (!equal) myRef.getAndSet(myDto);
            return equal ? ai.get() : ai.incrementAndGet();
        })).values();
```

**NOTE:** as @shmosel pointed out correctly, this approach will only work if you stream over your list sequentally.

Comment: This is stateful and won't work in parallel.

Comment: Granted it's a creative way to simplify.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks for your hint. I will add a corresponding note.
Since there is only one answer here, at least so far, which points to an external dependency, the OP may be satisfied with a solution that is suitable for sequential streams, especially since he/she is not explicitly looking for solutions that are also suitable for parallel streams.